# Redshift COPY command returns stl_load_error 1205 Invalid Date Format - length must be 10 or more

Tags: sql, copy, amazon-redshift

I am copying a .csv file from S3 into Redshift and the Redshift COPY command returns

- stl_load_error  1205
- Invalid Date Format - length must be 10 or more.

My dates are all 10 characters long and in the default 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

Command:

```
COPY [table]
FROM [file location]
ACCESS_KEY_ID [___]
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY [____]
FORMAT AS CSV
IGNOREHEADER 1;
```

The table was created using:

```
CREATE TABLE finance.commissions_life (
submitted_date date,
campaign varchar(40),
click_id varchar(40),
local_id varchar(40),
num_apps float);
```

And the .csv is in that exact format as well.

Is anyone else having a similar issue?

Comment: Hi Stoddard, did have similar issue. My way was to load data in a staging table making the submitted_date varchar(50). Once loaded, I can control the format when send the data to the final table. Try changing the submitted_date to varchar(50) and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the table I was uploading had an index that was offsetting the columns. The column that was supposed to be the ten-character date wasn't aligned with the date column in the database table.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7):

When I have run into this error in the past, I always fall back on explicitly defining both the delimiter to be used, and the date format:

```
COPY db.schema.table
FROM 's3://bucket/folder/file.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=[access_key];aws_secret_access_key=[secret_access_key]'
DELIMITER AS ','
DATEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'
IGNOREHEADER 1
;
```

If you have the ability to alter the S3 file's structure/format, you should explicitly wrap the dates in quotes, and save it as a tab-delimited text file instead of a CSV. If you can do this, your `COPY` command would then be:

```
COPY db.schema.table
FROM 's3://bucket/folder/file.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=[access_key];aws_secret_access_key=[secret_access_key]'
DELIMITER AS '\t' 
DATEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'
IGNOREHEADER 1
REMOVEQUOTES
;
```

Additionally, you should be able to query the system table `stl_load_errors` to gather additional information on the exact row/text that is causing the load to fail:

```
SELECT *
FROM stl_load_errors
ORDER BY starttime DESC
;
```

Answer (score 5):

Extending the answer provided by @John, use `dateformat 'auto'` in the copy command to have more flexibility. Also, if his answer resolved the issue, please mark it as accepted so that we know.
If not, can you query the system error table to see the erroneous records and edit your question to publish the "raw_line" or "raw_field_value" value ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was adding the date with quotes `"2018-01-03"`, it accepted the date `2018-01-03` without the quotes.

The error message is really misleading.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was receiving the error message as of **type mismatching**:

The target column was `Date` while the actual value to be loaded was a `Timestamp`. Converting the column to the correct Data Type fixed the issue for me.